# I would like to make a Multi level vertical menu without javascript or jquery i just need the CSS to make it

Tags: css

I'm looking for the CSS code to create a multi level vertical menu with no Jquery or javascript just pure CSS.

I have the HTML part done and ready to go!

Comment: Have you Googled for this? Have you written any code yourself?

Comment: yes i googled it all i found was programs that make em for ya and ones that require jquery

Comment: Can I ask why you need to avoid javascript? That may help in figuring out any other alternatives, or if maybe javascript might be the right tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow [this guide](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/create-a-multilevel-dropdown-menu-with-css-and-improve-it-via-jquery) until step 3.

In case that site ever goes down essentially what you are going to need to investigate is using the `:hover` selector to show and hide various parts of the menu at any given time.

Comment: that's for horizontal menus i need vertical

Comment: That is simply a CSS tweak, I am not going to write the thing for you.

Comment: then why bother answering my question

Answer (score 1):

The flyout menu from [www.cssmenus.co.uk](http://www.cssmenus.co.uk/flyout.html) might be worth looking at?

Comment: thank you this will work just need to tweek colors and change the tag name this will save me some time